# vis network node tooltip note showing

Tags: vis.js, graph-visualization, vis.js-network

I have added title field for node. As per `vis.js` documentation it should display  tooltip on hover of node.

I can see `vis-tooltip` div in inspect element. But its visiblity is hidden. In `vis.js` documnetation example I saw popup.css file getting applied to `vis-tooltip` class. But I don't see it in my application

I have following properties for nodes in options.  Do I need to add anything ?

```js
 nodes: {
        title: 'hover',
        shape: 'dot',
        chosen: true,
        color: {
            highlight: {
              border: '#2B7CE9',
              background: '#fff'
          },
          hover: {
            border: '#2B7CE9',
            background: '#D2E5FF'
          }
        },
        font: {
          size: 9
        },
        borderWidth: 2
      }
```

sample node data

```
{id: 9264, type: "db", title: "node-text", resource: "dascsvd", region: "xxxxx"}
```

Answer (score 2):

For `vis-tooltip` class css needs to be applied dynamically on hover. Which wasn't happening in my case. That css was coming frpm `popup.css` file. I copied those css and added to my code.
Now its working fine as expected

```css
::ng-deep div.vis-tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #f5f4ed;

  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #808074;

  box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  pointer-events: none;

  z-index: 5;
}
```

Comment: In which "vis.js documnetation example" did you see this, and where did you find `popup.css`?